# Find coordinate from distance and coordinate

Tags: coordinate-systems

I know that this topic has been done already but i believe that my issues is a bit more annoying.

I have a circle which I know its center's coordinate that cross a line like this :

```
   *****
-*-------*----  <-- The line 
*         *
*         * <------ The circle
 *       *
  *******
```

In addition to that i know the Y coordinates of my line. My problem is the following :

x1,y1 : the coordinates of the circle's center

x2,y2 : the coordinates of the intersection between the circle and the line

r     : the radius of the circle

Knowing x1,y1,y2,r is it possible to get x2 on an equation where x2 is the only element of the right part of our equation (i mean 'x2 = ?')

Comment: Use the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the distance between points formula

a^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y2)^2

The solutions of this equation is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah i did find that but i can't manage to get x2 alone on the left part of the equation that you and crazy for math mention. Thanks for responding as well